# Unable to send any emails from WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, azure, smtp

Hope you're doing good!
We have hosted a WordPress site on Azure.
We are facing an issue that we are unable to send any emails from our site. Can you look into this to manage to resolve this in their SMTP setup however from the beginning it didn't work for us? If any setting would have to set up here.
Looking forward to hearing from you!
Thanks

Comment: You'll need to be a bit more specific if you want to get help. For example: how exactly are you sending out emails? Where's the code you're using to do so?

Comment: Hi @cabrerahector, thanks for your reply. Actually, we have this domain https://myenergy.utilidex.com/ hosted on Azure however I have tried many plugins to send emails like contact from 7, wp form, etc. but unfortunately it is not sending emails. Because there is no SMTP set up on this website and we have been already set up the SMTP on Azure but it doesn't work. Can you let us the solution?